# .NET Core Angular 2 (2.4.10) Visual Studio 2017 migration: Failed to load html files

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've just migrated my VS2015 (.NET Core 1.1.0) project to VS2017 (.NET Core 1.1.1) and unfortunately my Angular 2 app doesn't work anymore.

At startup chrome console now shows the following errors:

[image]

My project structure is:

[image]

[image]

The "ClientApp" folder is inside the root folder and *webpack* execute the packaging and the minifing of the entire app, creating a *vendor.js* file in the wwwroot folder.

How can I resolve this issue? Someone has experienced this before?

Thanks all in advance :)

**EDIT**

I found the problem. 
In projects.component.ts I set template as `templateUrl: './projects.component.html'` and this works fine with .NET Core 1.1.0. 
With .NET Core 1.1.1 seems that it needs to be specified only as `template: require('.projects.component.html')`. 
Now it works fine!

Comment: Is it not just a case of your projects.component.html not being where the app is looking? It's looking in the root but it's in a sub dir? How is your routing set up? EDIT: Missed the sentence about minification. My mistake.

Comment: I found the problem. In projects.component.ts I set template as "templateUrl: './projects.component.html'" and this works fine with .NET Core 1.1.0. With .NET Core 1.1.1 seems that it needs to be specified only as "template: require('.projects.component.html')". Now it works fine!